# Flip image over a diagonal

Tags: java

I need to flip an image over an imaginary diagonal going from the top right to bottom left of an image. This is what I have so far. getBasicPixel(x,y) returns the rgb of the pixel as an int value.

```
public static void flipD(Picture p){
    int h= p.getHeight();
    int w= p.getWidth();
    int v=0;

    for(int i=0; i< h; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<w; j++){
            v=p.getBasicPixel(i,j);
            p.setBasicPixel(w-1-i, w-1-j, v);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: swapping things often follow this pattern `temp = a; a = b; b = temp;`

Comment: Should I create a new pixel object and use the swapping formula?

Comment: you have 2 things to swap. The `a` and `b` in your code are the pixels on opposite sides of the picture

Comment: Thanks I think that puts me on the right path

Comment: Can you guarantee that your picture will always be square?  If not, I'd create a new Picture.  In that case, there's no swapping-- it's all copying.

Comment: @phatfingers For this we can assume the picture is square

Comment: Even if you follow instructions to swap using a temporary variable, you still need to make sure you don't swap twice.  Creating a new Picture is your simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

This should just be a matter of trading x and y.  So, if one were doing this operation on an array it would look like this.

```
int portrait[][] = { {1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6} };
int landscape[][] = new int[2][3];

for (int row=0; row < portrait.size; row++) {
    for (int col=0; col < portrait[0].size; col++) {
        landscape[col][row]=portrait[row][col];
    }
}
```